# How can a native speaker understand "interviewed" mean "sex"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

In *Sweet Smell of Success* (1957), press agent Sidney speaks to club's buxom blonde, ditzy cigarette girl Rita about newspaper columnist Leo Bartha:

> Sidney: And, uh, were you... "**interviewed**"?
>
> Rita: In his apartment.
>
> Sidney: Where was his wife?
>
> Rita: I don't know. It's a big apartment. Only I wasn't **interviewed**.

How can a native speaker understand "interviewed" mean "sex"?

Comment: The metaphor is understood in context. *Interviewed** does not mean to have sex, but any number of verbs and phrases can be employed to hint at it.

Comment: We say in AmE: You had to be there. An idiom which means the context of something makes it clear.

Comment: The quote marks suggest an ironic tone of voice.

Comment: You need to be careful in attempting to learn English from 65 year old movies, or movies about sub-cultures, as this one appears to be. They use local variations that don't necessarily match standard language either then or now.  But... "It was a big apartment." LOL!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just about anything can mean sex if you hesitate with "uh", then pause with "..." then put it in "quotes". These are all things that convey sexual innuendo.

> Sidney: And, uh, were you... "assisted"?
> Sidney: And, did he, uh ... "repair your TV"?